# Why does `String#delete` return an error in my ruby code?

Tags: ruby

The goal is to take a string and return the most common letter along with it's count. For string `'hello'`, it would return `['l', 2]`.

I've written the following:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
list = []
bigcount = 0
while 0 < string.length
    count = 0
    for i in 0..string.length
        if string[0] == string[i]
            count += 1
        end
    end
    if count > bigcount
        bigcount = count
        list = (string[0])
        string.delete[string[0]]
    end
end
return [list,bigcount]  
end
```

I get the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
(repl):14:in `delete'
(repl):14:in `most_common_letter'
(repl):5:in `initialize'
```

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong with the `delete` statement, or what else is causing this to return an error.

I have a solution done another way, but I thought this would work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the `delete` function wrong

Use `string.delete(string[0])` instead of `string.delete[string[0]]`

**EDIT**

As for the infinite loop you mentioned.
Your condition for while is `0 < string.length`

And you expect the `string.delete[string[0]]` statement to actually delete a character at a time.

But what exactly it does is, it deletes a character and returns the new string, but it never actually mutates/changes the actual string.

So try changing it to `string = string.delete[string[0]]`

Comment: goodness!

I'm so careless. Thank you for pointing that out. Do you see any parts where there is an infinite loop? I'm not getting the desired results. the console doesn't return anything

Comment: I just moved the delete statement to below the third last 'end' but it still seems like it keeps looping

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. That worked like magic! Thank you for helping me understand

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `delete()` instead of `delete[]` which has already been answered...

Most of what you need is implemented in Ruby's [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) class natively. [`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count).

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  max = [ nil, 0 ]
  string.each_char {|char| 
    char_count = string.count(char)
    max = [ char, char_count ] if char_count > max[1]
  }
  return max
end
```

Comment: added to my notes! thank you for that - another good thing to remember. I think I did come across that before but wasn't too sure how to use it. I just began using 'for' statements in place of the 'while' statements lol

Comment: No worries, you might need [`downcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase) too, depending on your use case.

Comment: haha that's great. Sometimes I think of such methods (if that's what they're called) and I wonder how to find them (a good man in comments above mentioned the Ruby documentation and I now know how to fish). I was studying from App Academy's prep work lol. This place has been amazing for me so far. Thanks man! the goal is to do a career switch

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in a much easier way, if you allow me to say.

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  h = Hash.new
  string.chars.sort.map { |c|
    h[c] = 0 if (h[c].nil?)
    h[c] = h[c] + 1
  }
  maxk = nil
  maxv = -1
  mk = h.keys
  mk.each do |k|
    if (h[k] > maxv) then
      maxk = k
      maxv = h[k]
    end
  end
  [ maxk , maxv ]
end
```

If you test this with

```
puts most_common_letter("alcachofra")
```

the result will be

```
[ 'a', 3 ]
```

Finally, remember you don't need a **return** in the end of a Ruby method. The last value assigned is automatically returned.

Do Ruby in a Ruby way!

Comment: That's an interesting way. I haven't come across the 'hash' part you have there. That's a cool thing to remember. About the final return statement - it's just me being extra careful lol, but I'll get used to this. New to programming

Comment: I edited to make it still shorter. And I'm sure it can be even shorter if I keep thinkig about it. My suggestion, since you're new to programming, is to look the Ruby documentation and know about the methods for arrays and hashes. It helps a lot. Array: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html Hash: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html

Comment: Thank you sir. Yea i realized code can be constantly edited and optimized, but I've so far just doing practice problems and learned from there. I will look through those links and hopefully get good at this!

Comment: That's a lot of code for 'easier'. I would say the "Ruby" way is using it's plethora of native libraries to reduce code. Hash provides for a default value and `max_by` natively.  So 3 lines should do `counts = Hash.new(0);
  string.each_char {|c| counts[c] += 1 };
  counts.max_by{|k,v| v}`

Comment: I'm searching the documentation for Hash to learn more about max_by and found nothing. Would you mind to provide a link for this method? Here is the doc I'm reading: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html

Comment: Hash and Array are both Enumerable: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by. The "Included Modules" section will link you to a classes other methods.